# Why Resource Files Added in Qt Quick QML Project Are Not Displaying?

Tags: image, qt, qml, resources, desktop

As in the title, added resources does not appear in my project:

Why do the attached `.png` files do not appear in center of window?

[image: Why attached .png files does not appear in center of window?]

Code:

```cpp
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        source: "://Images/empty.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: true
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, is it this QML source code matter or have I failed resource files attaching?

I really don't know where the problem is. It seems I am doing everything exactly like in tutorials and documentation.

Where is the mistake?

Edit:

This is qrc resource code:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>Images/cross.png</file>
    <file>Images/empty.png</file>
    <file>Images/nought.png</file>
</qresource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. The first option would include to create a *.qrc file which contains all the assets and the assets/images are part of the project folder in some way.

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/infinity.svg</file>
        <file>images/lockOff.svg</file>
        <file>images/search.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In this case you can use "relative" paths and also define your own names for files via aliases. Have a look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#prefixes).

```
Image {
    source: "qrc:/images/infinity.svg"
}
```

To make that work the build system needs to process the resource file. Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#cmake). For CMake you need to set `CMAKE_AUTORCC` to `true` and add the *.qrc file to `qt_add_executable()`

The second option would be to use the absolute path prefixed with `file://`. Sometimes you need to use `Qt.resolveUrl()` ([documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#resolvedUrl-method)) to make it work.

```
Image {
    source: "file://<absolute path to image>/images/infinity.svg"
}
```

I can't really explain why `qrc:/...` is working and `:/...` is not. It might be because the `source` property of `Image` is a `url` and the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#runtime-api) says the following:

> You can also reference the Qt resource system through a QUrl. Use the
> qrc scheme in this case.

Comment: Thanks @iam_peter!  You convinced me to re-read this section of the documentation very carefully. As you said: very important is properly directory of *.qrc file in Cmake. There is the point: it has to be qt_add_executable (I have confused there) and also important is CMAKE_AUTORCC ! Thanks again, anyway a lot of learning ahead of me, I am shure it is worth of it, framework looks very nice, and it seems it has a great potential. Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Change source to this:

```
source: "qrc:/Images/empty.png"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have also tried that. Does not work

Comment: When I am trying with "qrc:" following error appears: "QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/Images/empty.png"

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#build-system-integration

Comment: Problem was somewhere else, but anyway you are right! Now it works with "qrc:" prefix and does not work without that. Thanks for help Jurgen Lutz. Merry Christmas and happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the full URL of your resources, they're

```
qrc:/main.qml
qrc:/Images/cross.png
qrc:/Images/empty.png
qrc:/Images/nought.png
```

If you're accessing your images from the `main.qml`, I would recommend relative references. i.e. it would be enough for you to go:

```
    Image {
        source: "Images/empty.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: true
    }
```

Whilst it didn't appear to be a problem in your case, be wary of some platforms that are case sensitive and be sure you're folder is `Images` and not `images` which requires diligent naming of the folder and the corresponding reference in the source code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! It is solved. Problem was in CMake File. Very impotant thing is to place qrc file in qt_add_executable, and also put following line: set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON). It should to be done manually. There is description in documentation, unfortunately I was impatient and I didn't notice, so result was: lost time. Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!